# Limit of integral of $\sin\frac{1}{t}$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

Determine whether or not the limit below exists.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{\sin x}\sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^{2}\mathrm{d}t$$
I tried to use the Mean value theorem integrals to prove the limit exists, but it does not exist for $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\sin \frac{1}{x}$. So I guessed the limit does not exist and used the Cauchy principle to prove it, but I failed.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: I propose to close the question as it has been changed in a way that answers can not be understood.

Comment: Is it $\cos t^2$ or $\cos^2 t$?

Comment: it is \cos(t^2).

Answer (score 2):

The map $f : t \mapsto \sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^{2}$ is bounded by $1$. As $\sin$ is also bounded, the integral is bounded too. Therefore the limit is equal to zero.

*Side comment: for $y \in \mathbb R$, the integral $\int_0^y f(t) \ dy$ exists as $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$ and continuous on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.*

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake of the limit of x, it should be $x\rightarrow 0$, not $\infty$

Comment: I suggest then that you open another question. Because having **moving questions** is really not good.

Comment: Really sorry for that!  Maybe next time, I already changed the question.

Comment: I suggest that you come back to the original question and open a new one. **If not, it becomes impossible to understand such a post.**

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you can easily majorate the integral using Triangular Inequality. Then, the limit should appear.
But you must be careful when writing the proof, considering that sin(x) is not constantly positive over $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake of the limit of x, it should be $x\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0):

As the question has been changed from the limit when $x \rightarrow \infty$ to $x \rightarrow 0$ here is a new hint :

You still have to think about the continuity of the map $ f : t \mapsto \sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^{2}$ for $t \neq 0$. Deduce from the behaviour of f around $0$ what happens to the integral when $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I think $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, but it does not mean that the limit of the integral does not exist,  do you agree?

Comment: Yes i agree with that. I forgot to write $t \neq 0$. I edited the post

Comment: I do not really get the weaker hypothesis you mention.

Comment: I missread your post when writing that. Sorry about that also. Did you find your solution tho ? What I was thinking about is the integrability of f around $0$.